# Move \answerline next to left margin instead of right

Tags: align, exam

I am using exam class and need to have the space for a short answer on the left of the page instead of the right when using \answerline.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This solution is far from pretty, but I was unable to find a solution in the documentation for the exam class.

My solution is to create a new function `\leftanswerline`, which wraps the normal `\answerline` in a `minipage`, which is then forced to the left by a negative `hspace`. Although not pretty, it seems to do the trick.

I have used the `xifthen` package to support for optional arguments to the `\answerline` command. If this feature is not needed, the `\leftanswerline` can be simplified to `\newcommand{\leftanswerlinetwo}{\par\hspace{-1.3em}\begin{minipage}{1em}\answerline\end{minipage}}`.

```
\documentclass[answers]{exam}
\usepackage{xifthen}

\newcommand{\leftanswerline}[1][]%
{\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}%
{\par\hspace{-1.3em}\begin{minipage}{1em}\answerline\end{minipage}}%
{\par\hspace{-1.3em}\begin{minipage}{1em}\answerline[#1]\end{minipage}}%
}


\begin{document}
  \begin{questions}
   \question First Question
   \leftanswerline[Left Answer Line]
   \question Second Question
   \answerline[Right Answer Line]
  \end{questions}
\end{document}
```